What does it mean when a system of Linear Equations have more than one solution?
Consider 3 linear equations where one is a linear combination of other two(which are not parallel). Say $a$, $b$ and $a+b$. Now $a+b$ is also a line right? Then how $a$, $b$ and $a+b$ can have more than one solution ? This can be only possible if all three $a$,$b$ and $c$ represent the same line. For example, $a = x + y + z = 8$, $b= 2x + 4y + 4z = 0$ and $c = a+b = 3x + 5y + 5z = 8$. Now this set have more than one solution but none of them are parallel to each other right? and $c$ is a unique line?

Typically, in Euclidean space, we would be thinking of each of those three equations as a plane. Two planes intersect in a line, if they are not parallel. A third plane, if it is not parallel to either of the first two, or a linear combination of the first two, will cut the line in a point.

Thanks for the reply mate, but why a non parallel plane ( which is a LC of other two ) not cut it into a point.

Look at the situation in 2D, which is a direct analogue of the 3D situation. If a,b are non-parallel lines, they intersect once. If you take a linear combination, it is a 3rd line with the same intersection - the new line is "twirling" about the solution. In 3D, two non-parallel planes always intersect in a line, and any linear combination of the two planes "twirls" about the line of intersection.

Got it, thanks :)

@ronno - sure, with a bit of elaboration

The post speaks of linear equations as lines but then uses three variables to describe them, so I'll treat both lines and planes in this answer.
In Euclidean space, we would be thinking of each of those three equations ($c_1x+c_2y+c_3z=k$) as a plane. Two planes intersect in a line, if they are not parallel. A third plane, if it is not parallel to either of the first two, or a linear combination of the first two, will cut the line in a point. This is easy to verify algebraically, but the best intuition is probably built by seeing with your eyes how planes interact with different parameters, using a plotting program or by hand drawing.
The Euclidean situation in $2D$ is a direct analogue of the $3D$ situation, and may be a better place to start. If $a,b$ are non-parallel lines ($c_1x+c_2y=k$), they intersect once. If you take a linear combination $\alpha a+\beta b$, it is a $3$rd line with the same intersection - the new line is "twirling" about the solution. In $3D$, two non-parallel planes always intersect in a line, and any linear combination of the two planes "twirls" about the line of intersection.
Consider too the effect of adding a $3$rd line that is not a linear combination of the first two. A third line parallel to either forms a transversal of two parallel lines, with two pairwise solutions to the equations, but no solution to all three. If the third line is not parallel and not a linear combination of the first two, we now have a triangle with $3$ pairwise solutions of the lines (the vertices). In either case we would say the the system of equations has no solution, for you cannot satisfy all three demands placed by the lines at once. The situation in $3D$ and beyond is analagous.
